# List all users that placed at least one order this month and also in the previous 12 months

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9cad653ea714883ba8eef92dccf5c0ca)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-03-09', 'user_01'),
('2020-09-08', 'user_02'),
('2020-11-23', 'user_03'),

('2021-05-02', 'user_01'),
('2021-05-08', 'user_01'),

('2021-05-08', 'user_02'),
('2021-05-10', 'user_02'),
('2021-05-11', 'user_02'),

('2021-05-12', 'user_03'),
('2021-05-20', 'user_07');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
order_date  |   customer  | 
------------|-------------|-------
2021-05-08  |   user_02   | 
2021-05-12  |   user_03   |
```

---

I want to extract all users that have **at least one order_date** `between 2021-05-01 and 2021-05-31` and also exist in the 12 months before this selected month, thus in the time `between 2021-05-01 and 2021-04-30`.

Therefore, I tried go with this query:

```
SELECT 
t1.order_date, 
t1.customer
FROM 

  (SELECT
   c.customer,
   c.order_date,
   LAG(c.order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer) AS prev_order_date
   FROM customers c) t1

WHERE t1.order_date BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-05-31'
AND t1.prev_order_date >= t1.order_date - INTERVAL '12 month'
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

This query almost gives me the expected result. 
However, the problem is that it also includes `user_01`. 
This is caused becasue the `user_01` appears mutliple times in `2021-05`.

How do I need to modify the query so even if a user appears mutliple times in `2021-05` he will only be included if he also exists in the period `between 2021-05-01 and 2021-04-30`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LAG()` is missing an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
LAG(c.order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer ORDER BY c.order_date) AS prev_order_date
```

I'm surprised `LAG()` works without an `ORDER BY`.

Presumably, you also want the previous order to be before the current month:

```
WHERE t1.order_date BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-05-31' AND
      t1.prev_order_date >= '2020-06-01' AND
      t1.prev_order_date < '2021-05-01'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fe7432a8e8982921d6a0c628b9e7dd52) is a db<>fiddle.

In case you want to go through multiple months you can use:

```
WHERE t1.order_date BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-06-30' 
AND t1.prev_order_date >= date_trunc('month', t1.order_date) - interval '12 month'
AND t1.prev_order_date < date_trunc('month', t1.order_date)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=797f4b24184b772349981cc4d11f5822) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It sill does not give me the correct result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d88190b370e1bcf410a7d953d69277ad

Comment: @Michi . . . I think you want the previous order to be before the current month.

Answer (score 2):

Just find all the records in current month then check if an order `EXISTS` in the past 12 months:

```sql
SELECT /* DISTINCT ON ... */ *
FROM customers AS c1
WHERE order_date >= '2021-05-01'::date
AND   order_date <  '2021-05-01'::date + INTERVAL '1 month'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM customers AS c2
    WHERE c2.customer = c1.customer
    AND order_date >= '2021-05-01'::date - INTERVAL '12 month'
    AND order_date <  '2021-05-01'::date
)
```